# Trim a string from a specific character on

Tags: vb.net, string, trim

I've got a textbox, its text property is a path such as this, for example:

```
/users/me/whatever
```

What I want is to delete the last "folder" and have this:

```
/users/me
```

I've tried things with the trim and split functions but for now I'm not achieving what I want.

edit:

```
Private Sub btn_Back_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Back.Click

    If Not (txt_Path.Text = "/") Then
        txt_Path.Text = ... ?
    End If

End Sub
```

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Split on /, string.LastIndexOf.. Regex loads of ways to do this. No code so don't know why you are struggling.

Comment: Just inserted the code in my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty simple:

```
Dim str = txt_Path.Text
Dim i = str.LastIndexOf("/")
If i <> -1 then
   txt_Path.Text = str.Substring(0, i)
End if
```

Comment: Thanks, not exactly what I was looking for but it'll have to do for now

Comment: @chiapa What were you looking for?

Comment: Oh, don't get me wrong, the result is exactly what I need but I was hoping to find some string function that removes everything from a specific character on, as in the title of my question!

Comment: @chiapa I dont think there is such a function built in, but you could easily create your own extension function to the string class using the code above if you need to reuse it in other places.

Comment: @chiapa give an example of the *specific character*. Also, this solution doesn't work when the path looks like this: "/users/me/whatever/"

Comment: @DanVerdolino, The specific character is "/", between "me" and "whatever". The solution actually works

Comment: @chiapa and for this string: "/users/me/whatever/" ? Both are valid path strings, but for this reason Microsoft gave you  `Path.GetDirectoryName()` which doesn't care about the formatting as long as it's a valid path. Btw "//users//me//whatever//" is also valid...

Comment: @DanVerdolino, I'm working with strings that are not real paths but act as such, they come from json objects. It's string manipulation I'm looking for and not real paths, in fact, the user can't have access to a real path. Nevermind man, it's solved

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Path.GetDirectoryName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

```
txt_Path.Text = Path.GetDirectoryName(txt_Path.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also parse this using a [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dim dir As String

' this may not work as expected if a user ends the directory with as slash, try it to see and then decide if that is ok or not?
' this regex pattern keeps everything except "everything that follows the last slash"
dir = Regex.Replace("/users/me/whatever", "^(.*)\/.*[^\/]$", "$1")
Console.WriteLine(dir)
```